# How to add formatted code into a mdx-code-block in Docusaurus?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, docusaurus

I need to add formatted code into multiple tabs in Docusaurus MDX.
I have this code, but it is not working:

````
```mdx-code-block
import Tabs from '@theme/Tabs';
import TabItem from '@theme/TabItem';
```

```mdx-code-block
<Tabs>
    <TabItem value="current" label="Current">
        ```php
            $event = request()->event;
            $causerName = request()->causerName;
            $causerLastName = request()->causerLastName;
            $action = request()->action;
            $role = request()->role;
            $initDate = request()->initDate;
            $finDate = request()->finDate;
        ```
    </TabItem>
</Tabs>
```
````

That's the graphical result:
[image]

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/core": "2.4.0",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "2.4.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "docusaurus-plugin-openapi-docs": "^1.7.0",
    "docusaurus-theme-openapi-docs": "^1.7.0",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^1.3.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/module-type-aliases": "2.4.0"
  },
```

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

After searching extensively, I discovered that formatted code can be added within another tag called CodeBlock and imported. Finally, the code appears as follows:

````
```mdx-code-block
import Tabs from '@theme/Tabs';
import TabItem from '@theme/TabItem';
import CodeBlock from '@theme/CodeBlock';
```
<mdx-code-block>
<Tabs>
<TabItem value="current" label="Current">
<CodeBlock language="php">
{`$event = request()->event;
$causerName = request()->causerName;
$causerLastName = request()->causerLastName;
$action = request()->action;
$role = request()->role;
$initDate = request()->initDate;
$finDate = request()->finDate;
`}
</CodeBlock>
</TabItem>
````

I hope this helps you.